# Insert into table doesnt work

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

i have this code, but i cant get it to insert any thing in my sql table?
the echoing out part works fine..

```
/* We have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
We can now output image to user's browser or store information in the database */       
$s_id = $_GET['id'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'table');
$query = "INSERT INTO table ( sp_s-id, sp_thump, sp_orig ) VALUES 
( '$s_id', '$thumb_save_folder', '$image_save_folder' )";
//added $conn variable in order to connect to our database.
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo '<div align="center">';

echo '<img src="uploads/'.$thumb_prefix . $new_file_name.'" >alt="Thumbnail">';
echo '<br />';
echo '<img src="uploads/'. $new_file_name.'" alt="Resized Image">';
echo $s_id;
echo '</div>';
imagedestroy($image_res); //freeup memory
```

Comment: It's the hyphen `sp_s-id` - SQL is translating this as "sp_s **MINUS** id" - use backticks around the column name. Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()` and you'll see what I mean. Plus, I hope `table` isn't the real/actual name. If so, wrap it in backticks also; it's a reserved word.

Comment: Is your column really called `sp_thump` and not `sp_thumb`?

Comment: ^^^ could be a typo, one never knows. I'm not putting in an answer for this. Keeping it safe in comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah that's why I asked. If not, then it's probably why his insert isn't working and what you mentioned as well.

Comment: @Ali You may very well be right about that. That's why adding error checking will also show if it's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table ( sp_s-id, sp_thump, sp_orig ) VALUES 
    ( '$s_id', '$thumb_save_folder', '$image_save_folder' )";
```

With this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` ( `sp_s-id`, `sp_thump`, `sp_orig` ) VALUES 
    ( '$s_id', '$thumb_save_folder', '$image_save_folder' )";
```

SQL server (as well as PHP or most other languages) can't handle column/table/variable names with a minus (-) in it, so you'd need to put them into quotes/ticks. It's highly recommendable though to follow the rule `[_A-Za-z][0-9_A-Za-z]*` for column/table/variable names (meaning only numbers, characters (A-Z) and underscores, but not starting with a number).

Also, you should ALWAYS validate or type cast user input, like this (validate):

```
$s_id = $_GET['id'];
if (!is_numeric($s_id)) {
    // invalid input / possible hacking attempt?
}
```

Or this (type cast):

```
$s_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: You're welcome to use what I said in [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573657/insert-into-table-doesnt-work#comment41765108_26573657) as to "why" it's failing and why OP isn't checking for errors.

Comment: Answer sponsored by @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Kypros LOL! Good one :) love it.

Comment: @nicolaiolsen Hyphen in `$s-id` also. Don't use those **ever**. Use underscores. `$s_id` - PHP sees this a "MINUS" also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for "copying" your answer, I didn't see it and you were simply faster than me. +1'd your initial comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "the $s_id part"?

Comment: now every thing works, but it doesnt get the id and inserting it into the table at sp_s-id

Comment: Some more details (PHP error, SQL error) would be necessary.

Comment: i dont get any errors, i just get an 0 in the table where sp_s-id int 10

Comment: upload.php?id=2 this is the url with the id i wound to add in sp_s-id

Comment: No need to be sorry, I said [`you were welcome`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573657/insert-into-table-doesnt-work/26573716?noredirect=1#comment41765171_26573716) to it ;)

Answer (score -2):

You syntax is wrong. Try this.

If you're not using object oriented pattern, I suggest using mysql over mysqli.

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
$db = mysql_select_db('databasename', $conn);



$query ="INSERT INTO tablename ( sp_s-id, sp_thump, sp_orig ) VALUES ( '{$s_id}', '{$thumb_save_folder}', '{$image_save_folder}' )";

$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($conn);
```

Try this. It should insert into the table. Make sure to put your variables inside {} when using within double quotes.

Comment: His syntax is fine. Get your PHP straight. :P

Comment: i think its not, it doest works on xampp also with single quotes surrounding variables in a statment rounded up with double quotes

Comment: @ali i have been on php since 2011 , i know atleast this :p i was talking about xampp and db statement nd said "sometimes" also

Comment: This will fail; outright. Column name `sp_s-id` - Rest of OP's code is fine and maybe even `table`, but unsure if that's the actual name for it.

Comment: I use xampp regularly and I don't see why should xampp be the problem. The way you're using is correct usage, you can wrap variables with curly braces inside double quotes strings, but you can also access them directly without using curly braces so what he's using is not wrong and your answer is not an answer to his problem.

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_` and you've given `mysql_` code. The column `sp_s-id` contains a hyphen. Read the comments under OP's question and the other answer given.